# Same IP Address for two different nodes on same network

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, network-protocols

I'm wondering if two nodes on same network/sub-network can have same ip addresses? 
Now i know that by definiton ip addresses are unique and that's how nodes are identified on network layer but i got this question in a quiz paper so is that possible anyhow?

For eg if i am on a private network and then if try to set same ip addresses for two different nodes it gives IP adress conflict but answer was YES in that quiz for this question.So if anybody can suggest any possible reason,it would be deeply appreciated.

Please let me know if it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

they can, but they must not.
If the client know or cache the mac address , it can comunicate with one node
but the next arp request can change the mac address and continue with the other.
It can send udp message to the wrong node , but broke tcp connections.

Comment: Yes i know what practical problems having same ip addresses can cause,i wasn't asking that.My question was  how can they have same ip addresses? i mean it gives ip addres conflict error if ip addresses matches. How to deal with that??

Comment: I do not know, perhaps the two nets are the same, but not connected. two 192.168.0.0/24 on multi network host.